# SwiftUI: Value is not updated on Textfield using NumberFormatter like currency

Tags: swiftui

I'd just like to know whether there's a bug in macOS or if I have to make changes in code with currency formatted `TextField`s.

My problem: just a simple `TextField` in SwiftUI like

```
TextField("amountOnDeadline",value: $startValue, formatter: Formatters.currencyFormatter)
```

The formatter ist pretty simple:

```
    static let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()
```

Build and run!
The offered field is displayed as currency field. Great! But when I enter a number like 123, the field is reset to 0.00 € (or the value displayed on start).
Only when I exactly mark the 0.00 without the currency symbol and enter a value, the new value is taken.

[image]

This is not very user friendly. Is it something I have to live with or is there a solution for this problem? e.g. a special config in NumberFormatter.

Comment: Which Xcode and SwiftUI version you are using?

Comment: xcode 14. Didn‘t work on 13, too. I always use latest version. Working on MacBook Air M1 with MacOS 12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `NumberFormatter` you can use [`currency(code:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatstyle/3796513-currency) `FormatStyle` with `TextField` [`init(_:value:format:prompt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-3fh51).

```
TextField("amountOnDeadline",value: $startValue, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "EUR"))
```

This will not reset the field to `0.00` even if you remove the currency symbol.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698767 on why this might not work right for all currencies. In short: changes to the $value might not be recognized unless the currency symbol is erased (again, for some currencies). A strange bug that still seems to exist in the most recent version of XCode (15.0.1) and Swift (5.9).