# SwiftUI TextField Currency Formatting Problem

Tags: swiftui, formatting, textfield, currency, usability

I'm running into a SwiftUI end-user, usability problem using a TextField to enter a currency amount.

The bound field is a double, initially set to 0 and when the text field is displayed, the prompt is $0.00.

The problem is that when the user wants to enter a value, they have to erase the 0.00 with the backspace key, manually.  Also, if they accidentally backspace over the $-sign, any value entered thereafter disappears!

When there are multiple currency fields, this is a real nuisance for the end-user.

I've seen suggestions on the Internet to set the `formatter.zeroSymbol = ""` in the NumberFormatter, but when `numberStyle = .currency` any value entered is lost/destroyed.

If I change the number style to `.decimal`, I can use the `zeroSymbol` option and it seems to work, but I lose the currency formatting.

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Following is a sample code that you can run that demonstrates this problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount: Double = 0
    
    let currencyFormat: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        //                formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Enter Amount")
            Spacer()
            TextField("", value: $amount, formatter: currencyFormat)
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar [SwiftUI: Value is not updated on Textfield using NumberFormatter like currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750245/swiftui-value-is-not-updated-on-textfield-using-numberformatter-like-currency)

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on the answer of @Zulqarnain Naveed:

```
TextField("",value: $amount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
```

Add the following lines of code. This will select all text in the text field when focussed:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                    if let textField = obj.object as? UITextField {
                        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this one:

```
TextField("", value: $amount, formatter: currencyFormat)
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
```

Use **this one:**

```
TextField("",value: $amount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
```

Comment: Thanks.  A couple of problems with this solutions: 1) It still doesn't clear the field on first entry and you have to backspace over the zeros, and 2) It's only available with IOS 16.  it DOES, however, allow you to backspace over the $-sign.

Comment: okay if you do not want to show $0.00 then you can remove them and your textField will appear blank by replacing "@State private var amount: Double = 0"
to this  "@State private var amount: Double?"

Comment: Further you can check your amount variable value with this piece of code.

if let amt = amount{

                Text("\(amt)")

            }

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that worked for me. It uses FocusState to switch between two formatters.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Enter Amount")
            Spacer()
            CurrencyTextField(title: "", value: $amount)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CurrencyTextField: View {

    var title: String
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    private let currencyNumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency

        return formatter
    }()

    private let decimalNumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false

        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, value: $value, formatter: isFocused ? decimalNumberFormatter : currencyNumberFormatter)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .focused($isFocused)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```